# An abbreviation for the command `{\scshape\bfseries}` in the preamble of the document

Tags: fonts

I frequently use the command `{\scshape\bfseries}` (For instance, I write `{\scshape\bfseries Something}`) in my document to create a certain font. Is it possible to avoid typing this command frequently in the document and instead writing a global command in the preamble of the code and invoking it later in the document ?!.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\newcommand\x[1]{{\scshape\bfseries#1}}`   ... `\x{Something}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method is to use `\DeclareTextFontCommand`:

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textscb}{\scshape\bfseries}
```

Of course, you need to choose a text font that supports it, in the example the Libertinus Serif font family.

But be careful with using it: small caps give a degree of emphasis, `\bfseries` add another. Not to mention triple emphasis when also italic shape is added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textscb}{\scshape\bfseries}

\begin{document}

Here is \textscb{Something} very important.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using `berasans` sans serif font family. Unfortunately, it does not work with this font family.

Comment: @HusseinEid As far as I can see Bera Sans has no small caps.